# Add Muliple X-Axis in MSChart

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

i created the chart using mschart in C#,Now i want to add Multuple X-axis in chart conrtol is it possible in mschart.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: and how many Y axis ?

Answer (score 0):

The MSChart supports Multiple Y-Axes, you can use this by swapping your axes values.